# How do I pass a parameter back to an anonymous callback function?

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about how this works. I'm not new to javascript and I have done this before, it was just a long time ago and I have since lost the code. I don't know what this scenario is referred to, as a search for the term `callbacks` doesn't seem to turn up any relevant information.

1) What is this operation called? (ie: callback, passback, etc)
2) What do I do in `doStuff()` to pass a parameter back to the anonymous function?

**Named Function/Object below**

```
function doStuff(param1,anonymousFunction){
   //what do I do here to pass a value to 'anonymousFunction()'?
   //Can I just declare a variable?
}
```

**FunctionCall with anonymous function as parameter below**

```
doStuff('string', function(variableThatIWantToAccess){
   console.log(variableThatIWantToAccess);
});
```

Comment: `doStuff` should call your function and pass that parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just:

```
function doStuff(param1, anonymousFunction) {
    anonymousFunction(param1 + " parameter");
}

doStuff('string', function (variableThatIWantToAccess){
   console.log(variableThatIWantToAccess); // 'string paramter'
});
```

AKA [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: So simple, I don't know why this was so hard to find. Thanks you sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doStuff(param1,anonymousFunction){
   //what do I do here to pass a value to 'anonymousFunction()'?
   //Can I just declare a variable?

   anonymousFunction( param1 );
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To pass data to a callback function, simply call the callback with the correct arguments.

## Example

```
function doStuff( callback, data ){
  callback( data );
}

doStuff( alert, 'a small dog' );
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F48tY/)

### Edit

The comments show that OP was wondering about jQuery.

An example of a jQuery-event-handler-like function.

```
function listen( eventType, callback ){
  document.addEventListener( eventType, callback );
}
```

Comment: My question is a little ambiguous, sorry about that, What I'm trying to to is pass the a variable BACK to the anonymous function from the doStuff method.

Comment: Is this more like what you were thinking?

Comment: No, the reason I'm asking is because of click events in jquery. The anonymous function has a parameter that can be used by its containing code (usually `e` by convention) and I'm wondering where that darned `e` came from and how to do the same thing myself. Thanks for the time though.

Comment: The `e` comes from jQuery's internal event handler. I'll update my answer to show an example.

Comment: Thank you for digging through the source for me, this is very helpful. Upvote for you but already chose best answer.